# Keyboard config won't apply

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running ubuntu 17 and I want to reconfigure my keyboard, thus I've made all the desirable changes inside my /etc/default/keyboard config and executed

`$ source /etc/default/keyboard`

but the changes didn't get applied.

I've also tried firing up

`$ setxkbmap -model 105 -variant , -layout us,it -option "grp:caps_toggle, compose:ralt"`

but to no effect...nothing I've tried seemed to get the newly made changes in the config apply. 
In the docs it says that I should use

`udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`

or reboot my system for the changes to apply, apparently I have no desire to reboot my system, I execute the command and nothing happens, that's, I still cannot change the layout using CAPS.
I've simply run out of ideas...
I know it is possible to configure it with something like

`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

etc but it's awfully inconvenient and terribly inefficient. After all what if I want to do a rather complicated configuration...
What am I missing? How do I do such a nonsensically trivial thing as configure my keyboard? 
I used to run arch and debian and those distros were generous enough to give me the opportunity to change the damn thing without too much of a hassle...

**EDIT**

`$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` yields the following list of tuples:

`[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'it')]`

The second command:
`$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` yields the following list:

`['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']`

And apparently it's supposed to be `grp:caps_toggle`...why it's `alt_shift_toggle` I have no idea...

Comment: Are you running a desktop, and if so, which one exactly? Also, what's the problem with rebooting? It's the easiest way to change the keyboard configuration system wide.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for replying. Yes, it's gnome. The problem with rebooting is that as it's stated in the docs there's a more simple way of doing that. Does it mean I have to reboot my system every time I change anything like that?! I have a hell of a lot of apps open and a few important processes running....I don't want them to shut down.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Alright, I've just rebooted the system and as expected it didn't help.

Comment: Please run these two commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` Then let us know what they output by editing your question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I just did and posted the output in the EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your user's settings override the system wide ditto as defined in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

The keyboard layouts seem to be fine. To define a compose key and change the shortcut for layout switching, it's easiest to install *Tweak* (the `gnome-tweak-tool` package) and do it from there. Such changes should be effective instantly.

Comment: So you want to say there's some other config file that I don't know of ?
Because no matter what I write in the `/etc/default/keyboard` it changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Albert: Yes. It's the `~/.config/dconf/user` file. (But that's not a text file.)